# Как сделать сетку изображений как на Pinterest?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, подскажет кто как сделать такую сетку,только фотка будет одна и та же повторяться. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть пример?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая цель делать версткой, почему не картинку такую сделать?

Comment: Да смотрится вроде бы не плохо, а как?

Comment: Тут нужно с задачей определится, если просто как картинка (т.е. нет интерактива, фотки не меняются) то версткой не нужно делать, если каждая плитка работает как ссылка - то гридом или флексом такое можно сделать

Comment: Нужна просто сетка с 1й картинкой, ссылки не будет.. не подскажете как реализовать?

Comment: В фотошопе тогда можно

Comment: Возможно я Вас не понял,но мне нужно чтобы на странице вывелось в виде такой сетки.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю задачу, что вы пытались сделать? Что не получается? По этому я уточняю какая задача такой сетки, если просто одну картинку продублировать множество раз то зачем, почему не грузить одну готовую картинку сделанную в фотошопе?

Comment: Сейчас попробую объяснить.. У меня размер превьюшек 400х400, а когда переход на статью вывожу эту же картинку она получается маленькой, тк других размеров нет и скрипт не позволяет.. Решил сделать такую сетку 400х400 в которой будет дублироваться картинка 200х135. В итоге получиться должно примерно как на картинке представленной выше. Надеюсь нормально объяснил

Answer (score 1):

Один из простых вариантов через `backgroung-image` с повторением

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.container:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/135/nature) 0 0 repeat;
  background-repeat: space;
  width: 300%;
  height: 300vh;
  top: -200%;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
          transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Но есть проблемы с адаптивностью
Обратите внимание на свойство `background-repeat: space;` из-за него и проблемы с адаптивностью.
Размеры

```
 width: 300%;
  height: 300vh;
  top: -200%;
  left: -50%;
```

Указал методом проб и ошибок

Другие варианты - построить через флекс или грид.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, буду смотреть что можно изменить